# Showing $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is not compact in box topology

Tags: general-topology

I was looking at this approach to show $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is not compact when given the box topology. [To show that $R^{\omega}$ is not compact in box topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161178/to-show-that-r-omega-is-not-compact-in-box-topology)

The covering given by the user is $\{(-\infty,a) \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots|a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

To show this would it just be: suppose some finite subcollection $\{(-\infty,a_1)\times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots,...,(-\infty,a_n) \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots\}$ covers $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$. Choose $a=\text{max}\{a_1,...,a_n\}$. Then $a \times 0 \times \cdots$ is not in the union of the elements of the finite subcollection, and is not covered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that cover works, and the point $\langle a,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ is indeed not covered by the subfamily in question.

Another argument is to observe that

$$\{x\in\Bbb R^\omega:x_n=0\text{ for all }n\ge 1\}=\Bbb R\times\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\ldots$$

is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^\omega$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. Thus, $\Bbb R^\omega$ has a non-compact closed subset and therefore cannot be compact.

Comment: Oh jeez, I suggested that an open set is a point. Let me adjust that.

Comment: @ScottFrazier: And I’ve adjusted the answer to match your correction.